Why doesn't my AlertDialog close when I click outside its boundaries or on the buttons in Compose
@Composable
fun ShowDialog(
    title: String,
    text: String,
    onDismiss: () -> Unit = {}
) {
    AlertDialog(
        onDismissRequest = onDismiss,
        title = { Text(text = title) },
        text = { Text(text = text) },
        confirmButton = {
            Button(
                onClick = onDismiss
            ) {
                Text(text = "OK")
            }
        },
        dismissButton = {
            Button(
                onClick = onDismiss
            ) {
                Text(text = "Cancel")
            }
        }
    )
}

When I click on my buttons or outside the dialog, nothing happens. Why and how to fix this? I have a solution in that I have a manual hiding using isShowingDialog, but it seems to me that is a crutch, and this component should handle this internally rather than manually.

That's how Compose works.
AlertDialog is a simple composable function. If it is present in the compose tree it is displayed, otherwise it isn't. You therefore need a state variable that indicates if the dialog should be shown or skipped:
var isShowingDialog by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }

if (isShowingDialog)
    ShowDialog(
        ...
        onDismiss = { isShowingDialog = false },
    )

If you want to show the dialog, set isShowingDialog = true (in a button's callback, for example). if you set it to false, it is hidden.
Also have a look at the documentation with its examples.
